# cocos2d-x simple example of EditBox, error undefined reference to

Tags: c++, makefile, cocos2d-x, fedora

I have a problem trying to add an EditBox to the example game (created by create_project.py), using cocos2d-x 2.2.2, Fedora 20 and Eclipse Kepler,

I added in the HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
using namespace cocos2d::extension;
using namespace cocos2d::gui;
```

and

```
CCEditBox *m_pEditName = CCEditBox::create(ccp(100,100),CCScale9Sprite::create("input_field.png"));
m_pEditName->setPosition(ccp(origin.x+visibleSize.width/2, origin.y+visibleSize.height*3/4));
m_pEditName->setFontColor(ccRED);
m_pEditName->setPlaceHolder("Name:");
m_pEditName->setMaxLength(8);
m_pEditName->setReturnType(kKeyboardReturnTypeDone);
addChild(m_pEditName);
```

Added to my HelloWorldScene.h

```
#include "cocos-ext.h"
```

And got an error

```
fatal error: cocos-ext.h: No such file or directory
```

I realized that the compiler is trying to find the .h file in the /usr/include or /usr/local/include so I added to my makefile

```
INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/extensions
INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk
```

and now I get another error, see below my makefile and the error

MAKEFILE

```
EXECUTABLE = thief

COCOS_ROOT = ../../..

INCLUDES = -I.. -I../Classes
INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/extensions
INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/external/chipmunk/include/chipmunk
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/cocos2dx/kazmath/include
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/cocos2dx/include
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/cocos2dx
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/external/
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/CocosDenshion/include
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/extensions/netwrok
#INCLUDES += -I$(COCOS_ROOT)/external/libwebsockets/win32/include


SOURCES = main.cpp \
        ../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
        ../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp


include $(COCOS_ROOT)/cocos2dx/proj.linux/cocos2dx.mk

SHAREDLIBS += -lcocos2d
COCOS_LIBS = $(LIB_DIR)/libcocos2d.so

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(STATICLIBS) $(COCOS_LIBS) $(CORE_MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(LOG_LINK)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(SHAREDLIBS) $(STATICLIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(CORE_MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(LOG_CXX)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $(VISIBILITY) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: ../%.cpp $(CORE_MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(LOG_CXX)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) $(VISIBILITY) -c $< -o $@
```

Console Log

```
02:56:14 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project thief ****
make all 
 CXX obj/release/main.o
 CXX obj/release/Classes/AppDelegate.o
 CXX obj/release/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o
 LINK bin/release/thief
obj/release/Classes/AppDelegate.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_AppDelegate.cpp':
AppDelegate.cpp:(.text.startup+0x72): undefined reference to     cocos2d::gui::Margin::Margin()'
obj/release/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `HelloWorld::init()':
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x50f): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite::create(char const*)'
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x53f): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::create(cocos2d::CCSize const&,     cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*, cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*,     cocos2d::extension::CCScale9Sprite*)'
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x59c): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setFontColor(cocos2d::_ccColor3B const&)'
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setPlaceHolder(char const*)'
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x5b8): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setMaxLength(int)'
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text+0x5c5): undefined reference to     cocos2d::extension::CCEditBox::setReturnType(cocos2d::extension::KeyboardReturnType)'
obj/release/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_HelloWorldScene.cpp':
HelloWorldScene.cpp:(.text.startup+0x72): undefined reference to     cocos2d::gui::Margin::Margin()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bin/release/thief] Error 1

02:56:15 Build Finished (took 777ms)
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

In order to setup my cocos2d-x I used this instructions 
[Building Cocos2d-x on RHEL / Fedora / CentOS Linux](http://voidfuture.com/2013/10/08/building-cocos2d-x-on-rhel-fedora-centos-linux/)

Thanks

Comment: Did that worked it out ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't found the solution yet. I am working on Windows now due to deadline and I will try to fix it after my deadline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add in "extensions/CocoStudio/GUI/Layouts/UILayoutDefine.cpp" or remove "cocos-ext.h" from your code.